# org.dom4j.DocumentException: Connection timed out: connect and Nested exception: Connection Nested exception

Tags: java, hibernate

I have changed my pc and i have reinstalled all: tomcat 8 and 6, netbeans 8, jdk 1.7, hibernate 4.3.4, but when i run the web app, i have this error.
In past with my old pc i don't have this error but the code and the lib are the same, this error happen when i try to get data from database

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Controller threw exception
org.dom4j.DocumentException: Connection timed out: connect Nested exception: Connection timed out: connect
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
..cut..
Nested exception: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
..cut..
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Controller threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class ..cut..HibernateUtil
at my.package.data.DataAccess.getUser(DataAccess.java:38)
```

this is HibernateUtil.java:

```
package my.package;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.service.*;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory1();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory1() 
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure(); 
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
        serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();
        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` indicates a required class is missing

Comment: Some jar is missing from your classpath.

Comment: May be some build issues. Try clean and build twice consecutively. cleaning two times helped me sometimes to getout of this kind of errors.

Comment: I have found the problem: i have added to the project both hibernate 3 and hibernate 4, probability there was some conflict. Now i have only hibernate 4 and there are no problems

Comment: but i don't still understand why in past(old pc) i didn't have this error with both hibernate 3 and 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem: i have added to the project both hibernate 3 and hibernate 4, probability there was some conflict. Now i have only hibernate 4 and there are no problems

Answer (score 0):

We have found there is a port inaccessibility. Port 80 was not opened at the Firewall level.Use wget command from server for https and http both. for http we were getting waiting time. So we have added the 80 port at firewall level and then restarted the jboss. it started working

Answer (score 0):

If you are upgrading Hibernate versions with `.hbm.xml` files, don't forget to upgrade your DTDs

e.g. `http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-2.0.dtd` => `http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd`

The error in the console is `ERROR org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver Don't use old DTDs, read the Hibernate 3.x Migration Guide!`